# -webkit-animation-fill-mode in safari

Tags: css, safari, webkit, css-animations

i am using keyframes to scale an element on my webpage. The problem is that the animation is running perfectly in chrome but its not running in safari. I am providing values at 0% , 80% and 100% in keyframes and everytime the animation ends it goes back to the properties defined at 80% and not 100%. i also used fill-mode to stop animation at last frame but still got no solution.

```
@-webkit-keyframes leftpageanim { 
0%{ -webkit-transform:scale(1); 
bottom:-26px; 
} 

80%{ 
-webkit-transform:scale(1.8) ; bottom:140px; 
} 

100%
{ 
-webkit-transform:scale(1.7); bottom:120px; } 
}
```

after the animation ends its again reverting back to properties of 80%

Comment: Could you share some code snippets?

Comment: @-webkit-keyframes leftpageanim {
 0%{
  -webkit-transform:scale(1);
  bottom:-26px;
 }
 
  80%{
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.8) ;
  bottom:140px;
  }
  100%{
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.7);
  bottom:120px;
  }
}


after the animation ends its again reverting back to properties of 80%.

Comment: May be the bottom css properties as applied in keyframes might be affecting the output.
If the user could post it on jsfiddle, will help.

Comment: I have created a simple fiddle to simulate the problem. You may have look http://jsfiddle.net/baltundal/jYDT6/

Comment: the fiddle created by Burak is somewhat similar to my problem. but i've also used " -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards " to stop the animation at the last frame.

Comment: I found that its not any code problem. the animation-fill-mode property does not work correctly in all safari versions prior to 5.1

 It always seems to get its “forwards” state from the 2nd keyframe.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes in the code. Look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jYDT6/9/). The animation now stops at 100%. That's what you wanted, right?

from:

```
.animator {
    -webkit-animation-name: leftpageanim;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
```

to:

```
.animator {
    -webkit-animation: leftpageanim 5.0s ease-in-out forwards;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
```